Parallel processing of the collection without intersecting
There is a single mongodb instance with a very big collection, for example  events_collection
There are N=4 instances of some microservice (nodejs)
Each instance should read (batched) documents from the events_collection and these batches should not intersect.
In other words, the events_collection will be partitioned into N parts. And each part will be processed by its own instance of microservice.
I've figured out the following solutions:

Use optimistic locks for batches. But it looks non-optimal, because the batches will intersect

Each microservice instance has a unique constant ID. All documents in the events_collections will be partitioned by ID document field. Each instance will fetch documents with condition {...id: instanceId, ...}. But this solution has an issue: if the number of instances N is not constant


Is there a better solution for it?

I have come across this problem several times.  The solution below was tested on mongodb v6.  It uses the splitVector command which is not exactly widely known.
db = db.getSiblingDB("testX");

d = db.foo.stats();
exact_count = d['count'];

if(true) {
    num_workers = 8;  // REPLACE with your number of workers

    print("size: " + d['size']);

    // Must divide desired num workers by 2 for split logic to work
    // e.g.  8 workers would yield 16 chunks.
    cc = num_workers / 2;
    splitSize = Math.floor(d['size'] / cc);
    
} else {
    splitSize = 5000000 ;
}

// Used to be we could split on chunks of 32000 bytes.  Now the engine
// says 1MB is the minimum!
splitSize = Math.max(1000000, splitSize);
print("splitSize:", splitSize);

enqueueWork("testX.foo", splitSize);


//
// Here is where workers can consume items on the queue.
// Along the lines of what the OP was looking for, there
// would be multiple threads of the following logic.
//
// As a quick example, though, we will not complicate things with threads
// but will show that 1 thread operating on the work will process exactly
// the proper amount of docs.

n = 0;
totProcessed = 0;

while(1) {
    work = dequeue("testX.foo");
    if(work == null) {
        break;
    }

    idmin = work['start'];
    idmax = work['end'];

    // Here is where we operate on the work!
    c = db.foo.aggregate([
        {$match: {$and: [ {"_id":{$gte:idmin}}, {"_id":{$lt:idmax}} ] }}

        // For our example, just get the count of the chunk we
        // are processing:
        ,{$count: "N"}
    ]);
    d = c.next();

    totProcessed += d['N'];
    n++;
}
print(n + " chunks");
print(exact_count + " total docs");
print(totProcessed + " total processed");


function enqueueWork(ns,splitSizeBytes=32000){
    split = db.runCommand({splitVector:ns, keyPattern:{_id: 1},
                           maxChunkSizeBytes: splitSizeBytes});

    current = MinKey;

    db.queue.drop();
    
    split.splitKeys.forEach(function enqueue(key){
            db.queue.insert({ns:ns, start:current, end: key._id})
                current = key._id });
    db.queue.insert({ns:ns, start:current, end: MaxKey})
        }

function dequeue(ns){
    return db.queue.findAndModify({
            query: {status:{$ne:"processed"}, ns:ns},
                update: {$set:{status:"processed"}}
        })
}

This allows num_workers to optimally chew through a set of work even if one of them slows down because the others can pick up the work in the queue.
